# Moving (not copying) part of a vector to another vector using C++98

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics, c++98

In C++11 we can do the following:

```
std::vector<int> A(n);
std::vector<int> B; 
// I want to move part of A (from A[start] to A[end]) to B
std::move(A.begin()+start,A.begin()+end,std::back_inserter(B));
// in C++98 there is no move operator, so use copy (assign)
B.assign(A.begin()+start, A.begin()+end);
```

Is there any way in C++98 to do something similar to C++11 implementation.
The goal is to save time and use move instead of copying the vector, do you have any idea?

In the real code, I am not using int, It is vector of object.

Comment: Just to clarify, does the real code use `int`s too? If so, moving parts of the vector is no different from copying.

Comment: `c++98` doesn't have move semantic... but for your example, move `int` is equivalent to copy it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , in the real code it is not int .... it is an object

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, move semantics are not available in C++98, (Since they were introduced in C++11), but for the example given, moving the integers is not much different from copying them, so the actual performance difference should be negligible, if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

While move semantics didn't exist in C++98, you can always write something that does the equivalent yourself for this situation.

A quick and easy way to do it would be to just introduce a "moveTo" function on your class that you plan to work with, and then just call that with the reference/pointer of where you want to move it to.

It's worth highlighting that I have said "on your class"; because as Arnav Borborah said, your example is too trivial to make a difference; but I highlight this option in case it's a poor example.